# AX 2012 On-hand Stock for Sales line

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

On AX 2009 we could add a column to an SQL report showing the sum of Picked and
Reserved Physical on-hand stock for each Sales Order line.  This was done by
adding the quantities for the Transrefid/Inventtransid entries on Inventtrans
with Statusissue of 3 or 4. This is no longer possible in AX 2012 where
Transrefid (now Del_transrefid) is no longer supplied and Statusissue 3 & 4
no longer appear.

I surmise that these values must exist in a database file but which?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the table `InventTransOrigin` to do the proper linking to the sales order line:

```
select sum(Qty) from inventTrans
    where inventTrans.StatusIssue == StatusIssue::Picked
    exists join inventTransOrigin
    where inventTransOrigin.RecId == inventTrans.InventTransOrigin &&
          inventTransOrigin.InventTransId == salesLine.InventTransId;
```

In AX 2012 the `InventTrans` record is split in two, where the `InventTransOrigin` table contains the constant per lot information. The `inventTrans.InventTransOrigin` field contains the `RecId` reference to the new table.

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't altogether clear:   I know about InventTransOrigin and

Comment: Then what is your problem?

Comment: Since we started using AX 2012 in February this year,  the only

Answer (score 1):

Instead of directly joining InventTransOrigin to Sales Line join through InventTransOriginSalesLine. Then the above statement can be modified like below.

```
select sum(Qty) from inventTrans
    where inventTrans.StatusIssue == StatusIssue::Picked
    exists join InventTransOriginSalesLine
        where InventTransOriginSalesLine.SalesLineDataAreaId = salesLine.DataAreaId &&
              InventTransOriginSalesLine.SalesLineInventTransId  = salesLine.InventTransId 
        inner join inventTransOrigin
             where inventTransOrigin.RecId == InventTransOriginSalesLine.Recid;
```